# NtQueryInformationThread always fails in my code?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I want to retrieve a process's thread's start address using a process ID and thread ID.
here is my code:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetThreadStartAddress(DWORD tid, DWORD pid)
{

 NTSTATUS ntStatus;

 HANDLE hDupHandle;

 DWORD dwStartAddress;

 HANDLE hProcess;

HANDLE hTread;

pNtQIT NtQueryInformationThread;

hTread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, tid);

NtQueryInformationThread = (pNtQIT)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationThread");

if(NtQueryInformationThread == NULL)
    return 0;
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
SuspendThread(hTread);
if(!DuplicateHandle(hProcess, hTread, hProcess, &hDupHandle, THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, 0)){

    SetLastError(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED);

    return 0;

}

ntStatus = NtQueryInformationThread(hDupHandle, ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, &dwStartAddress, sizeof(DWORD), NULL);
ResumeThread(hTread );
CloseHandle(hTread);
CloseHandle(hProcess);

CloseHandle(hDupHandle);



if (ntStatus != 0)
    return 0;

return dwStartAddress;
```

}

but ntStatus is always not 0. Why?

Comment: What is the value of ntStatus?  From the doc: "The forms and significance of NTSTATUS error codes are listed in the Ntstatus.h header file available in the DDK, and are described in the DDK documentation under Kernel-Mode Driver Architecture / Design Guide / Driver Programming Techniques / Logging Errors."

Comment: Did you enable the `SeDebugPrivilege` for the calling process? You should also check the return values from `OpenThread()` and `OpenProcess()`.

Comment: I have no idea what SeDebugPrivilege is! how can I enable it?
They are working well and not returning NULL.

Comment: Also `dwStartAddress` should be `PVOID`, especially when running on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `pid` points to the process you're trying to get information about, you're creating `hDupHandle` in the context of that remote process rather than your own.  Your own process might or might not have a handle with the same numeric value, but it isn't the one you intended to use.

Also, for the same reason, you're duplicating a random handle from the remote process rather than the handle you got from OpenThread.

The call to `DuplicateHandle` should be

```
DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hTread, GetCurrentProcess(), &hDupHandle, 
  THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, 0)
```

although I don't know why you're duplicating the handle in the first place rather than just using it directly.

Answer (score 1):

OpenThread & OpenProcess may fail (especially due to insufficient privileges). You need to make sure you have valid handles before you call NtQueryInformationThread.